# How does one use the GIDSignInButton Class in Association with Google Authentication?

Tags: xcode, swift, class, authentication, properties

Google has a class that provides the "Sign in with Google" button called GIDSignInButton. To customize the button you have to modify the included properties. How do you do this properly in Swift?

**The button variable:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleSignInButton: GIDSignInButton!
```

The properties are listed here: [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in_button)

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://studyswift.blogspot.com.ee/2016/03/google-sign-in-for-ios-create.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it; use these in the viewDidLoad() function to modify the button:

```
googleSignInButton.colorScheme = GIDSignInButtonColorScheme.Dark
googleSignInButton.style = GIDSignInButtonStyle.IconOnly
```